# How to retrieve contents of html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a dynamic table that number of lines is unknown in advance, when I click edit button, modal appears like here

[image: Screenshot]

Structure of my table is like this:

```
<table id="mainTab">
    <tr id="list112">
        <td>keyword</td>
        <td>
            <table class="subTab">
                <tr class="urls" id="listUr112">
                    <td class="user"> user1 </td>
                    <td class="url">url1 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="subTab" >
                <tr class="urls" id="listUr112">
                    <td class="user"> user2 </td>
                    <td class="url">url2 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="subTab" >
                <tr class="urls" id="listUr112">
                    <td class="user"> user3 </td>
                    <td class="url">url3 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr id="list113">
        <td>
            <table class="subTab">
                <tr class="urls" id="listUr113">
                    <td class="user"> user1 </td>
                    <td class="url">url1 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="subTab" id="listUr113">
                tr class="urls">
                <td class="user"> user2 </td>
                <td class="url">url2 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I need to recuperate contents of line clicked to edit it:
my problem is how to know how many have fork number 122 of users and how recuperate user1, user2, user3 and their urls for example.

Comment: what information exactly are you trying to fetch on click?

Comment: Hi I'm guessing English is not your first language, but I'm a little confused by your use of the word "recuperate". That means to get better (like in a hospital or after an illness). Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Jamiec - He means "*get*". (In french, "*to recuperate*" is also used to mean "*to get*".)

Comment: i want to get user1 ,url1,user2,url2 user3,url3 of fork number 12,  and i need to know if possible how many user this fork have .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you have not mentioned exactly where is your edit button. But, you can play with jQuery selectors like shown in below code. I am showcasing you code sample, considering that you have edit button on siblings of of users table (having class name as `subTab`).
You may use jQuery like below:

```
$('.edit-button').click(function(){
    var urls = $(this).siblings('.subTab');
    // Iterate through all selected users tables for a fork
    urls.each(function(){
        // Perform actions here with DOM elements
        // Below line of code will only display value on console.
        console.log($(this).find('.user').text());
    });
});
```

Comment: can i get users one by one ?

Comment: With `each` function used, you can iterate through each user. Try running this on your system.